Linear Algebra Done Right 4th Edition, Section 8C, Exercise 4
Problem
Suppose $V$ is a real vector space. Prove that the operator $-I$ on $V$ has a square root if and only if $\mathbb{dim}\ V$ is an even number.
What I Tried
It's easy to show that if $\mathbb{dim}\ V$ is even, and $e_1, e_2, ... e_n$ is a basis of $V$, then just define the linear map $Re_i = -e_{i-1}$ if $i$ is even, and $R e_i = e_{i+1}$ if $i$ is odd. Then $R^2 = -I$.
However, I'm not sure how to show that $-I$ does not have a square root if $\mathbb{dim}\ V$ is odd.

If $R^2 = -I$, then $\det(R)^2 = \det(-I) = (-1)^{\dim V}$.

Note that for any nonzero vector $x$, the linear span of $x$ and $Ax$ is a two-dimensional invariant subspace of $V$.
